# Couchdb replication from local server to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchdb, replicate

I'm trying to replicate my database from a local server to an EC2 instance, but I can't figure out how to deal with authentication. Here's what I'm trying:

```
curl -X  POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"source":"http://localhost:5984/test-papers","target":"http://EC2-public-DNS:PORT/test-papers","create_target":true,"continuous":true}'
```

But I'm getting

```
{"error":"timeout"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the port in security group of the instance has the port 5984 opened ?

Comment: Yes, the port is open. I'm wondering if there's a way to supply some sort of authentication? Do I need to use the private IP or DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it to work. In the local database, I had to change the `/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini` to:

```
[httpd]
port = 5984
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

and I had to do the same thing from the Ubuntu EC2 instance. Then I created an admin account on the EC2 instance and finally ran the replication from the local host:

```
curl -X  POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"source":"database","target":"http://ADMIN:PASSWORD@EC2-public-DNS:5984/database","create_target":true,"continuous":true}'
```

Hopefully that helps someone else some time!